# Check the existence of file on local network in Python

Tags: python, path

I have a database file on a server at "\192.168.1.110\avid\GavinH\SearchDrives\drivelibrary.db"
which the test cannot see.

However when I test for the file locally its find it no problem.
Is there a problem with the path? The file does exist in this location.

```
def testConnection():
    dbpath = "\\192.168.1.110\avid\GavinH\SearchDrives\drivelibrary.db"
    if os.path.isfile(dbpath):
        print True

    else:
        print False



if __name__ == "__main__":
    testConnection()
```

Is there a problem with using network paths like this in Python?
Any ideas?

Thanks
Gavin

Comment: always use forward slash in python

Comment: Or escape backslashes, so path would be like: `\\\\192.168.1.110\\avid\\GavinH\\SearchDrives\\drivelibrary.db`.

Comment: how do you do this if the remote hosts requires credentials?